# Picture and text not in the same line on Mac

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a website and I have a problem in the footer of the website on my end it's working fine but on my friends computer ( mac )  there is there is a problem

Link : http://yb.websites-drafts.tk

My computer : [my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04iit.jpg)
My friend's computer ( mac ) : [my friend's computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T04Vo.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet it is hard to help when you don't know what to help with

Answer (score 0):

Please set your location tag as `display: inline-block`, and the parent element add `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the window width to make it as two line. Final, please tell your friend to clean cache.

**update:**
As I checked your code, `.location`, you set `width: 305px` but please know that each font has different size although it is same font-size. So my suggestion is in `.location`, css below:

```
.location{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```